# Unwanted undefined in the web page output

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I was trying to apply `localStorage` I learned and was able to make a note-taking app.

But I am getting undefined along with the input notes in the output on the page.

This is the js code I am dealing with,

```
let button = document.querySelector('.add');
let text = document.querySelector('.text');
let info = document.querySelector('.info');

let notesarray = [];
let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
if (notes != null) {
    notesarray = JSON.parse(notes);
}
showNotes();
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("we entered");
    let text1 = text.value;
    if (text1.length > 1) {
        notesarray.push(text.value);
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesarray));
        console.log(notesarray);
        showNotes();
    }
});

function showNotes() {
    let ans;
    notesarray.forEach((e) => {
        ans +=
            `<div>${e}</div> <br/>`
    })
    info.innerHTML = ans;
}
```

This is the output

[image: output]

Comment: You can just check if `e` exist before append it to `ans`

Comment: When you use the browser's script debugger, where specifically is that value coming from?  What other value do you expect to be there and why?

Comment: The value is coming from the textarea, in HTML

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+string+starts+with+undefined) of [Why is there "undefined" text in the beginning of my string?](/q/41031256/4642212). You append to `ans` without initializing it.

Comment: Yes I initialised it and it worked, thanks.